# "Thank you for being my first customer."

Tags: english-to-german, grammaticality

How to say

> Thank you for being my first customer.

in German?

Is the sentence

> Vielen Dank, dass du mein/e erste/r Kunde/Kundin bist.

correct?

Comment: It's correct but a little bit too casual ...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in principle this is correct, though I'd suggest the use of the Höflichkeitsform in a customer relation:

> Danke, dass Sie mein erster Kunde/meine erste Kundin sind.

or:

> Vielen Dank, Sie sind mein erster Kunde.

It may sound somewhat stilted though in a daily business or shop, as of course sombody has to be number one in the morning. And it may be pretty obvious for instance in the bakery at 6 o'clock.

> Guten Morgen, Sie sind der/die Erste heute.

would be more businesslike.

Comment: Remark to your first example: normally, I would expect a comma between „Danke“ and „dass“. The latter is also written with a double s according to the current standards of spelling.

Comment: Ui, danke. Meine Achillesferse Zeichensetzung gleich offenbart ...

Comment: Passiert, kein Problem! Auch mit den Rechtschreibreformen kommt man gern mal durcheinander.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!!